# MNIST creating multinomal model with 0~5 labels (low accuracy)

Tags: tensorflow, keras, mnist, one-hot-encoding, softmax

I am supposed to run a model with 0,1,2,3,4,5 labels from MNIST data and check accuracy. I have to use one-hot encoding as well.

This is what I got:

```
> import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

from keras.datasets import mnist

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()


x_train.shape
y_train.shape


y_train[0:10]

x_train_new, y_train_new = x_train[(y_train==0) | (y_train==1) | (y_train==2) | (y_train==3) | (y_train==4) | (y_train==5)], y_train[(y_train==0) | (y_train==1) | (y_train==2) | (y_train==3) | (y_train==4) | (y_train==5)]

x_train_new.shape
y_train_new.shape

y_train_new[0:10]

y_train_onehot = tf.one_hot(y_train_new, depth=6)
y_test_onehot = tf.one_hot(y_test, depth=6)

x_train_final = x_train_new.reshape((-1, 784))
x_train_final.shape

x_test_new, y_test_new = x_test[(y_test==0) | (y_test==1) | (y_test==2) | (y_test==3) | (y_test==4) | (y_test==5)], y_test[(y_test==0) | (y_test==1) | (y_test==2) | (y_test==3) | (y_test==4) | (y_test==5)]
x_test_new.shape
x_test_final = x_test_new.reshape((-1, 784))


x_train_final = x_train_final / 255
x_test_final = x_test_final / 255

model = keras.Sequential([keras.layers.Dense(1,activation='softmax')])
model.compile(optimizer="sgd",loss="categorical_crossentropy",metrics=["accuracy"])

model.fit(x=x_train_final,y=y_train_new,epochs=5)
```

However, accuracy is really low after running it (0.1872). When I try to change Dense from 1 to 6, I get "ValueError: Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 6) are incompatible".
What is the problem then? Can someone help me to fix my code? :(
TIA

Comment: You need more layers in your model. One is not enough

Comment: @AndrzejO How can I do that without getting ValueError?

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing the one_hot encoded labels into model.fit while training the model. Also, now you have 6 labels (0,1,2,3,4,5), you need to mention those labels category count at the final layer of the model as per the provided dataset.

Please check this below fixed code:

```
model = keras.Sequential([keras.layers.Dense(6,activation='softmax')])
model.compile(optimizer="sgd",loss="categorical_crossentropy",metrics=["accuracy"])

model.fit(x=x_train_final,y=y_train_onehot,epochs=5)
```

Output:

```
Epoch 1/5
1126/1126 [==============================] - 5s 4ms/step - loss: 0.5173 - accuracy: 0.8729
Epoch 2/5
1126/1126 [==============================] - 3s 3ms/step - loss: 0.2819 - accuracy: 0.9251
Epoch 3/5
1126/1126 [==============================] - 3s 3ms/step - loss: 0.2440 - accuracy: 0.9325
Epoch 4/5
1126/1126 [==============================] - 3s 3ms/step - loss: 0.2251 - accuracy: 0.9365
Epoch 5/5
1126/1126 [==============================] - 3s 3ms/step - loss: 0.2133 - accuracy: 0.9387
<keras.callbacks.History at 0x7f22bd00cf10>
```

Please refer to this similar [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/classification) for more details.